# Who first invented and analysed algorithm of finding median in a stream of integers using two heaps?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, heaps, selection-problem

There is popular problem:

> Given that integers are read from a data stream, find the median of
>   elements read so far in an efficient way.

One of possible solutions:

Use max-heap for left heap (i.e. for elts lower than median) and min-heap for right heap (i.e. for elts higher than median). While receiving each new integer from the stream, add it to either left heap or right heap depending on comparison with current median. Keep left and right heaps balanced, if one of heaps bigger by one, extract top element and put to another heap.

[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-stream-of-integers-running-integers/) is a implementation of this solution.

This question is very popular in job interviews (I had that one), many people on the internet mention this algorithm (at least a few blogs/books about coding interviews).

But this algorithm looks like "noname" algorithm because nobody mentioned author of this algorithm.

I understand how this algorithm works. But I would be glad to hear academic sources about this algorithm.

Comment: I tried to consider edge cases: both heaps are empty, one heap has 1 element other has 0 elements, both heaps are equal in size, one of heaps is bigger by one. In each of these cases I considered a new element is being lower/equal/bigger to current median. I considered median as a whole number and as a mean of the two middle values. I.e. in total is 4*3*2 = 24 cases. I didn't stuck. But I'm curious who invented algorithm first and read from the source and compare my current understanding. It looks like it's a noname algorithm, but I believe that somebody in the past discovered this algorithm.

Comment: This has "exercise problem" flavor (and hardness), so there may not be an academic reference. But then, some things that required several articles to get right some decades ago are exercise problems today, so there may as well be one.

Comment: @Raphael It is often the case that a problem is hard when not one has any idea
of the answer, and much easier once it is know that someone has the
solution. The firing squad problem was open for two years, and was
solved in a few hours once it was known that a solution
existed. Huffman allegedly did not know he was solving an open
problem, when he found Huffman coding as a solution to a take home
exam (his MIT teacher had kept the information). This median problem
is trivial when one is told it takes 2 heaps, and pretty much so
without knowing that. But not before heap became commonplace.

Comment: I looked around for references, and the best I could find was this thread on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387497/find-median-value-from-a-growing-set and this paper of sorts:  http://denenberg.com/omf.pdf.  The latter doesn't have any references to the basic algorithm, so it's likely unpublished.